# How to Populate ListBoxFor in Mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.listboxfor

I have a list of type stored procedure which have an ID and a Name as data in it.
i have property of int type in model and a list of same stored procedure.
now i want to bind this information into ListBoxFor

in view i have written this

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.HobbyId, new MultiSelectList(Model.listHobby, "pkHobbyId", "Hobby"))
```

but i am getting an error

> The parameter 'expression' must evaluate to an IEnumerable when multiple selection is allowed.

Please Help how to bind.

Comment: Please post also the Model. What type is listHobby?. How you set values to it?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try that

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.HobbyId, Model.listHobby.Select(f => new SelectListItem { Text = f.Hobby, Value = f.pkHobbyId.ToString() }), new { Multiple = "multiple" })
```

listHobby is iEnumerable list on my sample

---

sorry if i mislead you, rushed to answer but you cannot get the result of the multiselect listbox into a guid or int variable (whatever type is your HoobyId is) you should have an array to grab the result like

```
public string[] SelectedHobbyIds { get; set; }
```

so there must be something wrong with your View Models so its better that u would post your view models to be checked

Comment: yes i get it i m returning the value in hobby id which is of int whereas i have to return in a collection.

Answer (score 5):

@ Chhatrapati Sharma,

In your controller, try this,

```
ViewData['anyName'] = new SelectList {
 Text = ,  // text from ur function
 Value = , // Value from function
 Selected = // if required
}
```

and in view, bind the viewdata like,

```
 <@Html.ListBox("docImages", ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["anyName"]))
```

For testing, try a sample selectlist item as follows,

```
ViewData['anyName'] = new List<SelectListItem>{ 
                new SelectListItem {Text = "First", Value = "0"}, 
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Second"), Value = "1"}, 
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Third", Value = "2"} 
                    };
```

If this sample works, then check your function "_supp.listDocImages()" and make sure it return IList

Answer (score 3):

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.HobbyId, Model.listHobby.Select(f => new SelectListItem { Text = f.Hobby, Value = f.pkHobbyId.ToString() }), new { Multiple = "multiple" })
```

HobbyId in expression must be ienumerable because you set multi select

Comment: it didn't work for me
// controller
public ActionResult AddEditSupplier(int id)
{
   clsSupplier _supp = new clsSupplier();
   _supp.lstDocImgs = _supp.listDocImages();// it's working fine
   _supp.lstDocFiles = _supp.listDocFiles(); // it's working fine
    return View(_supp);
}
//View
but in view both are not working
 @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.DocumentId, new selectList(Model.lstDocImgs, "documentid", "title"))

@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.DocumentId, Model.lstDocImgs.Select(f => new SelectListItem { Text = f.Title, Value = f.documentid.ToString() }), new { Multiple = "multiple" })